# CSS: Center align text while keeping other elements of the container to the left

Tags: html, css, flexbox, text-alignment, text-align

I am trying to create a header that contains a title that should be center aligned and some buttons that should be on the left. I'm trying to use flexbox and the **align-self** property but I can't get it to work.

Below is the code snippet:

```html
  <div class="container">
    <span>
      <button pButton type="button" class="btn" icon="fa fa-check" iconPos="left" (click)="save()" label="Save"></button>
      <button pButton type="button" class="btn" (click)="fileInput.click()" label="Load file"></button>
      <input hidden type="file" #fileInput accept=".json" (change)="loadFile($event)" />
      <button pButton type="button" class="btn ui-button-success" iconPos="left" (click)="lockPage = !lockPage"
        [icon]="lockPage ? 'fa fa-unlock' : 'fa fa-lock'"></button>
    </span>
    <span style="align-self: center">
      <input type="text" class="name" pInputText [(ngModel)]="model.name" (keydown.enter)="$event.target.blur()" />
    </span>
  </div>
```

and the css:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

However the *align-self* property doesn't work (the way I expect it to...) and the end result is this:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong and what is the *proper* way to get the title in the center of the parent container?

Comment: Why is the title in the input element?  Shouldn't it be inside some text holder like h tag or p?

Comment: Because the user must be able to change the title.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of align-self: auto you can use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Same result as above

Comment: https://codepen.io/saksija/pen/OJLerMV It is working. Did you even tried?

Comment: I clicked on your link and it's even worse. the 'teeeest' title is all the way to the right.I'm using chrome by the way. Same result in firefox as well

Comment: Oh, I see, I misread your question. Try margin: 0 auto;  It will take the same width from both side

Comment: Well at least that works in codepen (although not in my page for some strange reason). If you edit your answer i will accept it as correct.

Comment: ok fixed it in my page as well

Comment: There is one final problem with this solution. That is that the center element *begins* from the center and therefore it's not totally centrally aligned.